# Does Any keyword in sql gives distinct records when used in a subquery

Tags: sql, join, comparison, distinct, any

I looked at a query of "ANY" from a tutorial site which was like:

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID
                       FROM OrderDetails
                       WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

This query is returning 31 rows and no duplicates.

After this I tried to apply same query using Joins but I was unable to get result coming from above query.

Join query I used:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
WHERE OrderDetails.Quantity = 10
ORDER BY Products.ProductName;
```

This is returning 44 rows, and has duplicates included.

After I used `DISTINCT` in this join query with `ProductName`, I got the desired result.

Hence I want to know - does "ANY" clause produce distinct records?

PS: Same record came in both Join queries (with and without distinct) with Inner Join as Well.

Comment: ANY doesn't do any DISTINCT. But a JOIN can give you more rows.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: ANY is not an operator. =ANY is the operator. PS Your interest in =ANY seems to maybe be for returning just one value per group for a column that can have multiple values per group. That's a faq. [ask] [Help] [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence I want to know - does "ANY" clause produce distinct records?

No.  It is actually the opposite.  The records being chosen are those in the `FROM` clause.  So, in the first query, there are no duplicates in `Products`.  The `WHERE` clause is never going to generate duplicate records.  That is not a property of `ANY` in particular; it is also true of `IN` and `EXISTS` and any other comparison operation.

What is opposite is that the `JOIN` does produce duplicate records.  That is what you are seeing in the second query.  The table `OrderDetails` has multiple rows for a given product.

Note that `ANY` (and `IN`) do actually implement a type of `JOIN` called a *semi-join*.  So, there is a relationship between what these operators do and `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause.  However, semi-joins and anti-joins are different from inner and outer joins that are defined in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2):

A `join` is a completely different operation to that of `any` (or similar `all`).

`any` is a logical operator and in your example is used to determine whether each row in `Products` should be returned.

The most rows that could be returned is equal to the number of rows in `Products` if the boolean result of the `any` operator is `true` for each `ProductId`.

By joining the tables, the two inputs to the `join` operator are compared and matching rows are output, which means if a single `productId` is input from `Products` and the input from `Orderdetails` has two rows with the same `ProductId` values ie with `Quantity=10` the result is 2 rows are output, 1 for each matching row.